# Looking for name of siblings-first-depth-second traversal order

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, reference-request, trees, graph-traversal

I've had to come up with a traversal order/algorithm for a project, and I am wondering if it has a name.

The requirements of the algorithm are:

1. it visits the parent before the children.
2. it visits all the children in one group.
3. it is otherwise depth-first.

I basically modified a pre-order to visit the siblings all together, before going down to the child of the first sibling. Note that this is *not* breadth-first.

Here is an example of the traversal order:

[image]

As you can see, in this tree, the traversal would be `H, D, L, B, F, A, C, E, G, J, N, I, K, M, O`, and grouping for siblings: `(H), (D, L), (B, F), (A, C), (E, G), (J, N), (I, K), (M, O)`.

Some things to ponder:

- I think one can also view this as a pre-order traversal of the "dual" of this tree, where the dual nodes are representative of each group of siblings.
- Notice the z-shapes. It is like a "z-order-traversal", an analog to a z-order-curve, but for tree traversal. It has the similar property of traversing children together, just like a z-order curve will visit the siblings of the finest level of a full quadtree.

So, what is the name of this traversal order?

Comment: Yes, I would just call this pre-order, for the reason you state. Except that when a node is "visited" we actually look at its two children instead.

Comment: @HendrikJan well it is a type of pre-order, I was hoping for a more specific name, given its additional properties?

Comment: Well my view is that it *is* pre-order (with a twist). In pre-order each node is visited and some task is performed. Here the task is looking at the two children. I know, that is not competely fair, but too close to pre-order to look for another name. (But I like the intuitive Z-order you suggest too)